# Use Lagarith for encoding

Tags: video, compression, video-encoding, video-codecs

I have a loss less mp4 file (YUV 4:4:4) encoded using x264 with me. I want to convert it to loss less avi using Lagarith. Earlier, to compress using lagarith, I used virtualDub. But that option now goes out since virtualDub does not support mp4 files as input. Any suggestions on possible softwares that support lagarith output and take a loss less mp4 as input ?

This exercise to convert to loss less avi is part of an experiment on video codecs, so, an alternative measure won't be useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem a few days ago, and since this question is very high placed in Googles search results, I would like to contribute a solution. You can luckily do this with Virtualdub if you are going to add a plugin package called [FFInputDriver](http://codecpack.co/download/FFInputDriver.html). **Please look at my detailed answer here**: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/14513

It will allow you to import a lot more files than just avi, I have successfully rendered mp4 and flv files into Lagarith avi files with this! To any visitors visiting this page by Google: This is very probably your answer if you want to encode videos into the Lagarith codec! You can even change the file container afterwards (for example to mkv) with FFmpeg. [Take a look here](https://superuser.com/questions/378726/convert-from-mov-to-mp4-container-format).

Answer (score 0):

This is not the fastest answer but better late than never: you can use "**Xvid4PSP 6.04.Portable**". The name is a bit irritating, this program is awful and i use it for the most Video conversions (not for psp etc.). Supports Multithreading, therefore fast!
It`s freeware on http://www.winnydows.com/ .
Have a good time,
...